# Missing bytes when reading serial data(sent via arduino/bluetooth) with .cpp program

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, latency

I have been sending serial data with an arduino via bluetooth to my computer. Here is the sample arduino code.

```
long interval=10;
long previousMs=0;
int k=1000;
int K=9999;


void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMs = millis();

  if(currentMs - previousMs > interval) {
    previousMs = currentMs;   
    k=k+1;
    Serial1.println(k);
    if(k>K){
      k=1000;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the relevant part of my .cpp code that reads the data. I changed it a bit to print out the number of bytes read. It should be 6 every time (4 digits, carriage return, new line), but every once in a while it will give 5,4,3,2, or 1.

```
int read_bt(PORTTYPE port, char *buf, int bytes_to_read)
{
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeout;
    DWORD n = 0;
    BOOL r;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Project2\\Debug\\BT_Constant.txt", "w+t");

    GetCommTimeouts(port, &timeout);
    timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD; // non-blocking
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    SetCommTimeouts(port, &timeout);

    while (1){
        // Get and clear current errors on the port.
        if (!ClearCommError(fd, &dwErrors, &comStat))
            // Report error in ClearCommError.
            exit(0);

        // Get error flags.
        fDNS = dwErrors & CE_DNS;
        fIOE = dwErrors & CE_IOE;
        fOOP = dwErrors & CE_OOP;
        fPTO = dwErrors & CE_PTO;
        fMODE = dwErrors & CE_MODE;
        fBREAK = dwErrors & CE_BREAK;
        fFRAME = dwErrors & CE_FRAME;
        fRXOVER = dwErrors & CE_RXOVER;
        fTXFULL = dwErrors & CE_TXFULL;
        fOVERRUN = dwErrors & CE_OVERRUN;
        fRXPARITY = dwErrors & CE_RXPARITY;

        if (comStat.cbInQue != 0){
            // comStat.cbInQue bytes have been received, but not read

            r = ReadFile(fd,
                buf,
                bytes_to_read,
                &n,
                NULL);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n", n);
        printf("%d\n", n);

    }
}
```

I thought about sharing the output text file but I can't think of the best way to do that. Basically it is just a ton of "6"'s and its scattered with 1-5 in various spots.

I am working on an project with EEG data so a very high resolution and low latency is required. I was wondering if there was an issue with any of my code or if it was more likely a hardware issue with the bluetooth module I am using (HC-05 BT 2.0EDR).

If anyone can shed some light on to why this is happening I would definitely appreciate it!

Comment: There's no guarantee that any read will ever fill the buffer. You have to loop until you have everything you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The OS sends a "received new bytes on the interface" whenever it wants. If you send, let's say, the string "Hello" (5 bytes), it can (and usually does this) just notify you once that you received 5 bytes, but that's not guaranteed. It can notify you the first two bytes and then the other three, or 3-2, or even 1-1-1-1-1.

That's why you should see the return value of `ReadFile` which, I suppose, gives you the actual number of read bytes, and then loop until you read every byte you need.

We don't know what is the actual output of your program, but I bet that whenever you found some "5-4-3-2-1" they were paired in such a way that the sum was exactly 6..

Anyway, you say that you need a "low latency system". Then avoid printing it in text format (6 bytes), but use the binary mode (for any number under 65536 you need just two bytes).

Bye

Comment: The ReadFile function just returns TRUE or FALSE. But the value of &n gives the number of bytes. You are right, it is usually 6 but sometimes it will be 5 then 1 or 3 then 2, etc. So if I keep it in its current format, would my best bet be to try and concatenate the 2 "partial" values? I could skip them until there is a full size packet available, but would really like to record every value. I will definitely look into sending in binary. Kind of new at this, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: But... You are recording every packet! It is just splitting one packet in two halves, meaning that you will have to call `ReadFile` twice for every split packet. So yes, the right way to do this is to wait until the packet is full. Since you can "wake" in the middle of a packet, however, I suggest you to check for a `\n` before starting to accumulate. For your application, however, I again suggest you to use binary format. If the greatest number you have to send is 10000 (14 bytes) you can send two packets, one with a 1 followed by the highest 7 bits and one with a 0 and the other 7, so you

Comment: can discriminate between the high part and the low part of the number, thus avoiding misinterpretations

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will definitely look into sending the data as binary, as that seems to be the better method.